# SQLAlchemy Query Dynamic Field

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have a table with many columns --

```
class Dummy(object):
    __tablename__ = 'dummies'
    c1 = Column(Integer)
    c2 = Column(Integer)
    c3 = Column(Integer)
    ...
    cN = Column(Integer)
```

Can I query through all columns *individually* without specifying each column name manually? --

```
for i in range(1, N):
    c_name = 'c%d' % i
    dummy = DBSession().query(Dummy).filter_by(???=0).first()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over the columns in a table.  First, the table:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.attributes import manager_of_class
dummy_table = manager_of_class(Dummy).mapper.mapped_table
```

and finally, the query

```
for col in dummy_table.columns:
    dummy = session.query(Dummy).filter(col == 0).first()
```

Or maybe, you actually are generating a specific set of columns from a more elaborate function than you're showing.  In which case, use `getattr`.  No, really.

```
for i in range(1, N):
    c_name = 'c%d' % i
    dummy = DBSession().query(Dummy).filter(getattr(Dummy, c_name) == 0).first()
```

Comment: Having this pattern is a sign that you might not have enough columns.  better add some more.  In all seriousness, this antipattern indicates that you should consider factoring out the list of columns into a new table, with a foreign key back to the `Dummy` table, the column value, and possibly an index to keep the items in order.  That will also make the query easier.

Comment: Thank you sir, I seriously under-estimated the flexibility of SQLAlchemy and should have tested out the getattr myself. As for the db design, let's just say that such NoSQL-like efficiency could be justified in some cases.

Comment: Well, I don't know about that, N indexes with N queries can slow things right down when compared to an inner join with just one index.  Even read heavy access patterns work well when you ask the database the right questions.